# SQLite database Error for Select query in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am passing string to the below code and it gives error :

```
Error: 08-24 12:57:55.583: E/AndroidRuntime(11640): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:    near "RAMDEV": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT chnno FROM EPG WHERE title = BABA RAMDEV KA YOGA
```

My code is here:

```
public String SearchChnNo(String title){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + chn_no + " FROM " + EPG + " WHERE " + pgm_title + " = " + title ; //error

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    String chnno = cursor.getString(1);
    return chnno;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expecting `pgm_title` is String you have to put `title` in Single Quotes,

```
pgm_title + " = '" + title+"'"
```

So, your final query would be,

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + chn_no + " FROM " + EPG + " WHERE " + 
                                             pgm_title + " = '" + title+"'" ;
```

Comment: I am getting error again  08-24 13:15:04.443: E/AndroidRuntime(12181): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3

Comment: sorry....agin error     08-24 13:37:20.224: E/CursorWindow(12863): Bad request for field slot 0,1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1

Comment: public String SearchChnNo(String title){
  
     String chnno = null;
     
  String selectQuery = "SELECT " + chn_no + " FROM " + EPG + " WHERE " + pgm_title + " = '" + title+"'" ;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      
        
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                chnno = cursor.getString(1);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
 
        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
 
        // returning
        return chnno;
     
    }

Answer (score 1):

Lalit Poptani's answer is correct, but I advise you to use the selection arguments of the raw query method , in the following manner :

Each time you need to write values inside a query, write a **question mark** instead.

Then, you have to add the values themselves inside an **array of strings**.

In your case, it will look like this :

```java
public String SearchChnNo(String title){

    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + chn_no + " FROM " + EPG + " WHERE " + pgm_title + " = ? " ;
    String selectionArgs [] = new String [] { title };

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase ();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery ( selectQuery , selectionArgs );
    // The default value, if none is found
    String chnno = "N/A";
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst () )
        chnno = cursor.getString ( 1 );
    // Do not forget to close the cursor
    cursor.close ();
    cursor = null;
    return chnno;

}
```

Comment: i am geeting this error   08-24 13:19:07.236: E/AndroidRuntime(12308): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: You should do cursor.moveToFirst before the getString call

Comment: You are trying to get the cursor ,but the cusror is not initiated it seems.

Answer (score 0):

To add to both Leeeeelo and Lalit answers, what you should really do instead is:

```
SQLiteDatabse db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(EPG, new String[] {chn_no}, ""+pgm_title+"=?", new String [] { title}, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst(); // that assumes there are results, you should probably make sure this returns true
String chnno = cursor.getString(1);
cursor.close();
return chnno;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public String SearchChnNo(String title){

    String chnno = null;

   String selectQuery = "SELECT " + chn_no + " FROM " + EPG + " WHERE " + pgm_title + "   = '" + title + "'" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            chnno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(chn_no));
            //chnno = cursor.getString(chn_no);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning
    return chnno;

  }
```